# Google Apps Scrollpanel not updating with information

Tags: google-apps-script

My script is iterating through some spreadsheet information.  I read the documentation and the scrollpanel is only allowed one child.  I therefore wrapped the horizontal panel information inside a scrollpanel but for some reason the scrollpanel never shows up with contents just the colored background.  Any ideas why this may be?

```
 var myscrollpanel = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(100, 100);
  myscrollpanel.setWidth("100%");
  myscrollpanel.setStyleAttribute("background", "silver");
  var vpanel = app.createVerticalPanel();


 for (i=1; i <= mylastrow;++i)
{

 var cellsname= mydatarange.getCell(i,1).getValue().toLowerCase();
// Browser.msgBox(cellsname );
// Browser.msgBox(searchstr.toString());
 if (cellsname.toString() == searchstr.toString()) 
 {

   var panelrow = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var ddate = app.createTextBox();
   var sbehavior = app.createTextBox();
   var sconsequence = app.createTextBox();
   var scomment = app.createLabel();
   var steacher = app.createTextBox();
   ddate.setText(mydatarange.getCell(i,5).getValue());
   sbehavior.setText(mydatarange.getCell(i,8).getValue());
   sconsequence.setText(mydatarange.getCell(i,6).getValue());
   scomment.setText(mydatarange.getCell(i,10).getValue());
   steacher.setText(mydatarange.getCell(i,7).getValue());
   panelrow.add(ddate);
   panelrow.add(sbehavior);
   panelrow.add(sconsequence);
   panelrow.add(steacher);
   panelrow.add(scomment);
   vpanel.add(panelrow);
   app.add(panelrow);


   cnt = ++cnt;

 }

 }  

//  Browser.msgBox(cnt);     

 myscrollpanel.add(vpanel);
app.add(myscrollpanel);
// return myscrollpanel;

return app    ;// update UI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few "anomalies" in your code that could cause some issues, I suggest a couple of changes (see code below).

Another point is that it is not a good idea to read a spreadsheet in a loop, it is mush more efficient to read the whole range in one time and then use the array values to iterate.
Here is a code proposal, I didn't test it (and it will probably need some debugging) but put a few comments to explain the changes.

```
  var myscrollpanel = app.createScrollPanel()//.setPixelSize(100, 100);// 100 pixel is quite small to put all the items you add !!
  myscrollpanel.setWidth("100%");// 
  myscrollpanel.setStyleAttribute("background", "silver");// this will not affect the widgets you add to the panel...
  var vpanel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var data = mydatarange.getValues();// get all data in an array

 for (i=0; i <data.length;++i)  // and work directly with array values (indexed to 0 instead of cells indexed to 1)
{

 var cellsname= data[i][0].toString().toLowerCase();
 if (cellsname == searchstr.toString()){
   var panelrow = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var ddate = app.createTextBox();
   var sbehavior = app.createTextBox();
   var sconsequence = app.createTextBox();
   var scomment = app.createLabel();
   var steacher = app.createTextBox();
   ddate.setText(data[i][4].getValue());
   sbehavior.setText(data[i][7].getValue());
   sconsequence.setText(data[i][5].getValue());
   scomment.setText(data[i][9].getValue());
   steacher.setText(data[i][6].getValue());
   panelrow.add(ddate);
   panelrow.add(sbehavior);
   panelrow.add(sconsequence);
   panelrow.add(steacher);
   panelrow.add(scomment);
   vpanel.add(panelrow);// add only to the panel, not to the app or the row will be outside the panel
   cnt = ++cnt;
   }
 }  
  myscrollpanel.add(vpanel);
  app.add(myscrollpanel);
  return app    ;// update UI
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I do not understand why you can only add to one location.  Is this an issue where it actually acknowledges it can only exist in one location and by adding it from one to the other moves it?

Comment: not sure I understand you point but yes, a single panel (or any widget) can only exist once in a IU. btw I left a typo in the code , the for loop must start on 0 (`for (i=0; i <data.length;++i)` )

Comment: just another detail, I see you are using Browser.msgBox() (I suppose) to check some variable values... use preferably the logger (Logger.log(any variable) that you can see after function execution in the menu>view>logger of the script editor.

Comment: I guess my point was in traditional coding objects can be referenced in multiple locations.  For example when drawing something in Objective C I can have it create multiple objects in multiple panels despite having the same information inside.  In this instance I have an idea of why/how it is working as it is not creating a new object when it is added merely placing it there.  Thanks for the logger tip as well.  Will be using that from now on.